# how to determine the column address

Tags: verilog, memory

Does a normal ram require to have row and column address decoder?
From the ram verilog coding that i get from http://www.asic-world.com/examples/verilog/ram_sp_sr_sw.html. 
In the verilog coding, it shows that it has 8 row address and 8bit long data. So when write operation enabled, the 8bit data will move into mem at specific address. From that we can determine the row address what about the column address?

Answer (score 1):

From the link mentioned, the **data width** and **address width** is **8-bits**. So, you can address a total of **256 byte** (2^8=256) memory space. This is same as `RAM_DEPTH` (1<<8=256). Also note the **width of** `data` is **8-bits**.

During a **write**, address is decoded and **single row** is selected. On that **entire row**, `data` is written. That means, **all the 8-bits** are written **altogether**. So, there is **no** need of *column selection*.

```
parameter DATA_WIDTH = 8 ;
parameter ADDR_WIDTH = 8 ;
parameter RAM_DEPTH = 1 << ADDR_WIDTH;
//...
inout [DATA_WIDTH-1:0]  data;
input [ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] address;
//...
mem[address] = data;
//...
```

Similarly, during the **read** phase, the **output data** is defined as:

```
reg [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] data_out ;
```

So, whenever a read command is issued, an **entire row** from memory is **fetched** from given address and it appears on output lines.

Lets have a look at **sample memory** shown below. In the sample memory, *data width* is *four bits* and depth is *eight bits*. If input address is `3'b100` and input data is `4'b1010`, then **all** the four bits are written in he memory. Hence **whole** row in filled with data.

[image: Memory]

Coming to your question:

> Does a normal ram require to have row and column address decoder?

The **row address decoder** is required to select a particular **address/place in the memory**. While **column address** is **not** mandatory to be present.

In some protocols, an additional *byte enable* selection is provided to write on particular bytes. But that is not the case here. If you have let's say **64-bit memory** and you want to write **4 bytes** data, then an additional **byte-enable** is to be provided to **mask** other bytes.

Refer to [Memory Basics](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~eedwards/compsys/memory/), [Memory interfacing pdf](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwja9uqr_MHJAhWUUY4KHStmAiYQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ce.yildiz.edu.tr%2Fpersonal%2Fsongul%2Ffile%2F2060%2F7_Memory_Basics.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFx4kCEJ_2QeobU52LqM2Bq9MC_0Q&sig2=IhALOP814bKH_ttmTiij6g) links.

Comment: Hi sharvil thanks for reply. another question to ask if i wanted to find the address decoder fault how should i write the verilog coding?

Comment: @avelyn If I get you correctly, you are asking about the fault in decoding the address by decoder?? If we provide address as `3'b101` and data is written on `3'b110` address?? Is it something like this? So this shall be covered by functional verification. You write some dummy data on some address and read from the same and compare both values. Have I got your question properly??

Comment: Hi sharvil like the address decoder fault on this slides 37 link http://www.ee.ncu.edu.tw/~jfli/memtest/lecture/ch02.pdf

Comment: Yeah. You need a directed testbench for finding these faults. For example, taking fault A and B, you write on all the addresses in memory and read from each one. (W-R-W-R pattern) The data that you had written should eventually pop out during read, if this doesn't happen, there is a bug/fault in the design. Fault C and D can be detected by writing to addresses and reading all the addresses, the data on one of the address which you have written shall be the only match. All this is to be done by a testbench, may be in SV.

Comment: For further clarifications, [lets continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32540/talk-between-avelyn-and-sharvil111)

Comment: erm sry sharvil but in order to use the chat feature i require to have 20 reputation but i only got 3 so is thr any other way i can chat with you for more detail?

Comment: ok i had added you